# Remove thumbnail images from category page

Tags: magento2, category

I am trying to remove the images from the category page. I am trying to do it within the admin pannel as I only want to remove the images for one specific sub category. Can anyone help out with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your admin panel.

Go to Products > Catalog and select a product you want.

Scroll down to Images and Videos section and click on the image.

Unselect the "Base" role and save.

That should remove the image form the category view. Please reference to this article for more info: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/magento/magento-images/

---

Or you can use this code to remove images from category pages:

In app/design/frontend/vendor/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Add:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
```